# Using avro schema (avsc) for writing avro data to s3 in Java Spark Job

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro

I want to write a DataFrame in Avro format using a provided Avro schema rather than Spark's auto-generated schema. How can I tell Spark to use my custom schema on write?

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "name1",
  "namespace" : "com.data"
  "fields" : [
  {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "string"
  },
  {
    "name" : "count",
    "type" : "int"
  },
  {
    "name" : "val_type",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "enum",
      "name" : "ValType"
      "symbols" : [ "s1", "s2" ]
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

1. avro reading with the using of avroSchema. On this step everything is ok.

   Dataset d1 = spark
   .read()
   .option("avroSchema",String.valueOf(inAvroSchema))
   .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
   .load("s3_path");
2. here I perform some spark.sql on above data and storing to DataFrame.
3. When I tried to write avro data to s3 based on avro schema

DF datatypes:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- val_type: string (nullable = true)
```

FinalDF.write().option("avroSchema",String.valueOf(inAvroSchema)).format("com.databricks.spark.avro").mode("overwrite").save("target_s3_path");

I got the error:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    ......
    Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: **Not a union: "string"**
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.getTypes(Schema.java:299)
        at 
org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroSerializer.org$apache$spark$sql$avro$AvroSerializer$$resolveNullableType(AvroSerializer.scala:229)
```

Is there any way to use avro schema for writing the avro data or if it's right approach (with `"option("avroSchema",String.valueOf(inAvroSchema))"`) - may be I'm doing something wrong? `"forceSchema" option` doesn't work in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think the problem has more to do with `"type" : "enum",` , can you change it to string and check if it works?

Comment: Thanks @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy    Yeah, I know it. It works with string. I should follow by provided avro schema (I have more fields there, it's just part and most of them are enum). I found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24855 and it's in progress, and for spark 3.0. We are using 2.x. May be I need to use DatumWriter. But how to write down spark dataframe with using GenericDatumWriter. It's question :)

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging around and I found something interesting,

```
case class Name1(id: String, count: Int, val_type: String)

val schema = """{
                   |  "type" : "record",
                   |  "name" : "name1",
                   |  "namespace" : "com.data",
                   |  "fields" : [
                   |  {
                   |    "name" : "id",
                   |    "type" : "string"
                   |  },
                   |  {
                   |    "name" : "count",
                   |    "type" : "int"
                   |  },
                   |  {
                   |    "name" : "val_type",
                   |    "type" : {
                   |      "type" : "enum",
                   |      "name" : "ValType",
                   |      "symbols" : [ "s1", "s2" ]
                   |    }
                   |  }
                   |  ]
                   |}""".stripMargin


val d = Seq(Name1("1",2,"s1"),Name1("1",3,"s2"),Name1("1",4,"s2"),Name1("11",2,"s1")).toDF()

d.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("avro").option("avroSchema",schema).save("data/tes2/")
```

The code above fails when I execute the code with spark 2.4.x, however when I run the same code with the new Spark 3.0.0 the code succeeds and the data is successfully written.

```
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("data/tes2/")
df.printSchema()
df.show(10)

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- val_type: string (nullable = true)

+---+-----+--------+
| id|count|val_type|
+---+-----+--------+
| 11|    2|      s1|
|  1|    4|      s2|
|  1|    3|      s2|
|  1|    2|      s1|
+---+-----+--------+
```

I guess the best idea would be to upgrade spark version or change the avro schema definition.

Comment: Hi @Sai Kiran KrishnaMurthy did u try to convert his success file with ->> java -jar avro-tools-1.9.2.jar tojson --reader-schema-file test.avsc out_java_avro.avro > out-java.json.  
 ?  Interesting if it converted without errors.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't work. It looks like they just suppress the schema check.

Comment: yeah. It's just left to use GenericDatumWriter and Reader. Convert DF to GenericRecord or some other object, then apply avro schema and then convert back to DF for writing to s3. (but I'm not sure if scheme will be preserved). I need to investigate if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.spark:spark-avro` package and try to set `avroSchema` option on the `to_avro` function. here is the doc:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro

Comment: Thanks @Hossein Torabi. Seems to be it can be apply (the schema) for 'from_avro' func only.

Comment: @SergiiChukhno No! you can use it on the t_avro too.

Comment: Hi Hossein, could you please share any example with to_avro func and applying of the avro schema?